# Asymptotic expansion of the solution of a Heat Equation

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

Given $g$ is differentiable function such that $g(0)=0$.
Prove that an asymptotic expansion of an integral: $$u(x,t) = \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{-x^2/4\tau}}{\tau^{3/2}} g(t-\tau) \ d\tau$$ for a fixed $t \gt 0$, as $x \to \infty$ is $$u(x,t) = e^{-x^2/4t} \ \bigg( \frac{8 t^{5/2} g'(0)}{\sqrt{\pi}x^3}\bigg)+ \mathcal{O}(x^{-4})$$

**My Approach**

I took the factor $e^{-x^2/4t}$ out of the integral and I was left with $$u(x,t) = \frac{x \ e^{-x^2/4t}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{(x^2/4)(1/t - 1/\tau)}}{\tau^{3/2}} g(t-\tau) \ d\tau$$

Second step: Let $G(\tau) = \frac{g(t-\tau)}{\tau^{3/2}}, \ \phi(\tau) = \frac{\tau -t}{4 t \tau}, A = \frac{x \ e^{-x^2/4t}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}$

So, I am left with $$u(x,t) = A \int_{0}^{t} e^{x^2 \phi(\tau)} G(\tau) d\tau$$

Rewriting the integral as by dropping $A$ for now $$u(x,t) =  \int_{0}^{t} \frac{G(\tau)}{x^2 \phi'(\tau)} d(e^{x^2 \phi(\tau)}) \  =  \frac{G(\tau)}{x^2 \phi'(\tau)} e^{x^2 \phi(\tau)} \bigg|_{\tau =0}^{\tau = t} \ - \ \int_{0}^{t} e^{x^2 \phi(\tau)} \ \frac{d}{d\tau}\bigg[\frac{G(\tau)}{x^2 \phi'(\tau)} \bigg] d\tau$$

Even after solving further, I am not able to get to the required answer. Can someone comment on if there is a problem with my approach?

Comment: Is the asymptotic expression supposed to be
$$e^{-x^2/(4 t)} \left( \frac {8 t^{5/2} g'(0)} {\sqrt \pi x^3} +
 O(x^{-4}) \right)?$$
If we take $u = 1/\tau$, then, for a sufficiently well-behaved $g$, Watson's lemma gives
$$f(u) = c_1 (u - u_0) + O((u - u_0)^2),
\quad u \to u_0, \\
x \int_{u_0}^\infty f(u) e^{-x^2 u /4} du =
c_1 x \int_{u_0}^\infty (u - u_0) e^{-x^2 u /4} du + O(x^{-5} e^{-x^2/(4 t)}),
\quad x \to \infty,$$
where $u_0 = 1/t$. However, if $g(t) = |t|^{4/3}$, then $g$ is differentiable but $u(x, t)$ is not $O(x^{-4} e^{-x^2/(4 t)})$.